# It takes time to display data in html page

Tags: angular, data-binding, delay

When user clicks on view button in user list, I want to display data of particular user on different page. I have fetch data form API. When I click on view button in user list, I get redirect to view page and also get all user data in console form API.

But user data is not display in view html page. The following is the code I have tried.

**Component Code ts file**

```
mediaData: any = {};  
getMediaType() {
let media_id = this.media_id;
this.service.getSingleMediaType(media_id).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.mediaData = res[0];
    console.log(this.mediaData);
  },
  err => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (err.status == 401) {
        this.router.navigate(['/others/signin']);
      }
    }
  }
);
}
```

**Following is my html code**

```
<div class="pb-1">
    <div>
<mat-label>Upin</mat-label></div>
         <mat-form-field>
             <input matInput readonly value="{{ mediaData ? mediaData?.upin: ''}}">
         </mat-form-field>   
    </div>        
 <div class="pb-1">
    <div>
<mat-label>Bid Type</mat-label></div>
        <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput readonly value="{{ mediaData ? mediaData?.type: ''}}">
        </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

**Following is service function**

```
getSingleMediaType(media_id) {
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}getMediaType/${media_id}`);
 }
```

PS: Some time data is display after some time, but some time it is not display. When I open console log on view page, user data is display. I don't understand how this is happening.

Comment: When do you call `getMediaType()`? Can you show some code ?

Comment: I call `getMediaType()`  in **ngOnInit**  
Following is my code `ngOnInit() {
    this.media_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // console.log(this.media_id);
    this.getMediaType();
  }`

Comment: can you post the console output of `console.log(this.mediaData);` statement?

Comment: @prabhakaran its a json object `{addr: "Nr. Rakhiyal Gujarat Botling Circle, Navnirman Co. Op. Bank Corner, 132 Foot Ring Road, Right side of Rakhiyal to Nagarvel Road Rakhiyal"
bid_type: 1
connect_area: "1"
del_flag: 0
det_addr: "NA"
disp: 1
foot_spec: "Circle"
h_height: 12
h_width: 12
hoard_details: "ASD"
hoard_name: "ASD"
id: 1
illu: "2"
land: "Rakhiyal Circle"
licno: ""
media_ext: "None"
media_road: "hoarding-0"
media_type: 5
media_ward: "DUDHESWAR"
media_zone: "5"
mtype: "ROAD PACKAGE"
pack_details: ""
pack_name: ""
}`

Comment: i don't see `upin` or `type` properties exists in above json object. Try adding console statements `console.log('upin',this.mediaData.upin);
console.log('type',this.mediaData.type);` in next to current console statement to verify the expected data is arrived.

Comment: @prabhakaran `{type: "Individual Media"
upin: "AMCADVT1415C0121"}`  
this is the json object with type and upin

Answer (score 0):

ok so I guess your response data looks like this

```
class MediaData {
    upin: string;
    type: string;
}
```

You should use Angular forms, I prefer to use reactive forms, but you could use template driven forms as well (it will closer to what you have already done).

Initialize your mediaData object properly:

```
mediaData: MediaData = {
    upin: '',
    type: '',
};
```

this means you will have to add the type to the http request.

```
getSingleMediaType(media_id) {
    return this.http.get<MediaData>(`${this.apiUrl}getMediaType/${media_id}`);
}
```

```
getMediaType() {
    this.service.getSingleMediaType(this.media_id).subscribe(
      (res: MediaData[])=> {
        this.mediaData = res[0];
        console.log(this.mediaData);
      },
      err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status == 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/others/signin']);
          }
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Then to use the forms:

```
<div class="pb-1">
    <div>
        <mat-label>Upin</mat-label>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput readonly  [(ngModel)]="mediaData.upin" name="upin" id="upin">
    </mat-form-field>   
</div>        
<div class="pb-1">
    <div>
        <mat-label>Bid Type</mat-label>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput readonly [(ngModel)]="mediaData.type" name="type" id="type">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: how will having reactive forms Or having a Type definition in service fix the data not showing up issue?

Comment: types is good practice; doesn't fix anything but you will catch bugs much quicker.. Using the angular data binding abilities will be easier. You are already using the framework. btw I showed you template driven forms not reactive.

Comment: when i use like this `<input matInput readonly [value]=" mediaData ? mediaData?.type: ''">` it gives undefined

Comment: I just read the comments on the original post. You need to show the response from the http request, that it looking like the problem. That is why types help. Is your response body an array of MediaData objects? cause that is what it looks like , but if it isn't then that is the problem.

Comment: @JoeyGough yes it is array of mediaData objects 
`{type: "Individual Media" upin: "AMCADVT1415C0121"} ` 
this is response what i get from API

Comment: @sang, you mean `[{type: "Individual Media" upin: "AMCADVT1415C0121"}]`?